# ExtJS hidden field with a store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

in ExtJS, is there anyway to create a hidden field with a 'store', meaning that when I load the page, the hidden field will make a request to the server based on a url and store the value within itself. Similar to what `src` does for `image` or what `store` can do got `grid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve that is to invoke custom ajax request. Example:

```
var hiddenField = [...];

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'foo.php',
    success: function(response, opts){
        hiddenField.setValue(response.responseText);
    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {
        alert('Error');
    },
    params: { foo: 'bar' }
});
```